# How do I give a GCP service a URL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a website hosted on Google Cloud Platform (set up by someone else). The website has acceptance tests it runs before changes are pushed to the production branch, but the GCP set up seems to be unable to run the tests. [It appears that there is a missing URL in the acceptance tests service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCC9m.png), and from what I can tell this may be causing the issue as other services have a URL there.

I don't know what the particular name for this URL is. I have tried redeploying the build, tried editing the YAML files and found no way of adding a URL here. I have an idea of what the URL that this service needs to access is, but I just have no idea of how to add it into the service.

Comment: What service do you use on Google Cloud? How to you provision/invoke your acceptance service? Can you share more details?

Comment: The screenshot appears to be from Cloud Run. You did not post enough details from the logs. The health check seems to be failing, so the container did not startup correctly.